# How to launch a Qt application as tray icon without a window

Tags: macos, qt, menu, dock, trayicon

My purpose is to create a Qt tray application without an automatically shown main window. The startup of this app, is a tray Icon with a menu.

The problem is that my dock icon is still showing up for my application.

1. How do I prevent the dock icon from appearing?
2. If the answer involves adding entries into the generated `pfile`, how do I add those to my project, such as that these entries are generated automatically into my `pfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Qt Wiki : Technical FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_do_I_add_a_custom_Info.plist_to_my_Mac_application_with_qmake.3F):

> **How do I add a custom Info.plist to my Mac application with qmake?**
>
> You can set your own `Info.plist` by setting the `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST` variable to your `Info.plist` file. qmake will add a rule in the Makefile it generates to copy this over. If you don't specify this, qmake provides a generic `Info.plist` file.
>
> ```
> QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = MyInfo.plist   # qmake will copy this file to MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
> ```